# Simple time distance problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Every day a cyclist meets a train at a particular crossing. The road is straight before the 
crossing and both are traveling in the same direction. The cyclist travels with  a speed of 10 
Kmph. One day the cyclist comes late by 25 min. and meets the train 5km before the 
crossing. What is the speed of the train?

It would be great to have an explanation along with the answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears the cyclist and train are traveling parallel, but in opposite directions.  Hint:  draw a graph with time horizontal and cyclist position vertical.  The cyclist path is a straight line at what slope?  Put on a point for the crossing.  The new cyclist position is a parallel line 25 min to the right of the original one.  The new meeting point is 5 km below the old one.  You now have two points on the train's path, so measure the slope.